# Embedded ethernet issues for stm32f207zg using Lwip and HAL library

Tags: embedded, stm32, ethernet, cortex-m, lwip

I have a server -HAL library based- implementation that works correctly with one client.

**FreeRTOS**:

It first was made adding FreeRTOS and using netif API. It was made for UDP and TCP versions. But the same result when connects with more than one clients. After some working hours, we get a hardfault we are unable to track. As we are not FreeRTOS experts and our trying FreeRTOS methods were unuseful, we decided to remove FreeRTOS from de compilation. So we now are using RAW api.

**No FreeRTOS**:

Here TCP echo server gets hardfault after some hours with 3 client connections. After this, we try to run UDP echo and we have seen that after some days working under the same test, server attended 70milions of requests with no hardfault. We manually stopped execution. We don't know if hard fault would be achieved some commands later.

Now we've replaced the server echo answer by some microcontroller's GPIOs read/write results answer. It sends the result into a data payload less than 20bytes.
There is hardfaults sometimes but some other ones there is "MAC stop receiving data" (not hard fault) due to DMA doesn't free the descriptor (no flag error detection is set). The not hard fault error situation it's impossible to revert unless you resets the mcu. No hal_deInit plus hal_Init mac resets MAC reception.

Application uses LwIP stack being configured for working with static POOL for pBuf in lwipoptions.h. Reading/writing GPIOs operations are not using dynamic variables. I have declarated static arrays of 17 uint8 type elements. Client application is made by python running on a windows 11.

We have spent a lot of weeks trying to get an ethernet communication between a server an more than one clients. Application achieves hardfault or no more MAC reception point.
I try to ask for Lwip, FreeRTOS, HAL or microcontroller issues at everywhere. But the only that I found is a lot of people with similar situations.

Taking in to account all of my observations about developers claims, absence of examples, developers's posts with not solved issues, there is for me no evidences that a server (TCP neither UDP ones) with multiple clients connections could be achieved using Lwip and Cortex-M3 devices.

- Could anyone with enough experience on emebbed ethernet field say if what I'm concluding has any sense for him/her?
- Should we throw this microcontroller and Lwip stack to the trash for this project?
- Should we throw away the idea of having a server attending up to 10 clients running on any microcontroller (not microprocessor) for this kind of project?
- Does this server-client communication target need an stm32 device upgrade?
- **Is there any evidence that this device is able to support up to ten multiple client connection**? Maybe this is the wrong device. Has someone successfully done this before?

Comment: Can you run it with a debugger attached, and put a breakpoint in the hard fault handler? Then you might be able to get a stack backtrace, or examine some CPU registers to see what the cause of the fault was.

Comment: @pmacfarlane thanks for your attention. We did every time we have hard fault. We gone to see the registers where to find the address with the source of fault. We opened the disassembly view and the address that was on that register bring us to an address with no  information. Sorry but I don't remember the message that was on this view. But I rememeber that the address on that register was an address value too far from the last code address. I will repeat the breakpoint on there and I will tell you what  environment show me.